# How can I implement Docker outside of Docker setup for Jenkins using Docker Desktop for Windows?

Tags: docker, jenkins, devops, docker-desktop

I'm trying to create a CI/CD infrastructure using Jenkins. Considering recoverability, performance and maintainability topics I decided to handle both Jenkins and agents as Docker containers.

There are some certain restrictions that I cannot workaround:

- Cannot build this setup on Linux environment (IT policy)
- Cannot use WSL2 on Windows (I don't know when IT department will release regarding Windows update that supports WSL2)
- Security is a very high priorty topic

As far as I see, Docker outside of Docker setup is the proper way to implement. If I run the container as root using the command below, I can bind the docker.sock file and Jenkins jobs can create containers from Dockerfiles as agents:

```
docker run --name dood `
-d -u root --restart on-failure `
-p "8080:8080" -p "50000:50000" `
-v //var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock `
-v /usr/local/bin/docker:/usr/bin/docker `
jenkins/jenkins:lts
```

However, it doesn't work if Jenkins container is run with non-root user. This is not acceptable as it creates vulnerability. Suggested way is to run the container without root user and assign "jenkins" user to "docker" group:

```
groupadd docker
usermod -a -G docker jenkins
newgrp docker
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't work. "Got permission denied..." error occurs when Jenkins jobs try to create agent containers. I restarted Docker Desktop and container but result is the same. I am not sure but possible reason might be the Windows environment. This may work in Linux environment.

As a final effort, I tried the solution that is described in a [stackoverflow topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65158710/windows-docker-desktop-dial-unix-var-run-docker-sock-permission-denied). I noticed "setfacl" command does not work when Docker runs with Hyper-V. If I switch to WSL2 on my demo PC then the commands below solve the problem:

```
gpasswd -a jenkins docker
apt-get install acl
setfacl -m user:jenkins:rw /var/run/docker.sock
```

Unfortunately, target Windows environment does not support WSL2 so I cannot use this solution. Moreover, setfacl command is not persistent but this is another story.

An alternative solution might be activating "Expose daemon on tcp://localhost:2375 without TLS" option. However, this is not acceptable in security point of view so I cross it out.

I am curious if it is even possible to implement Docker outside of Docker setup for Jenkins on Docker Desktop for Windows. Considering the named restrictions, I am open to alternative setups/solutions as well.

I am quite new to Docker and not very experienced with Jenkins. If I use wrong terminology or approach please let me know.

Comment: Not an answer, but from my experience linux permissions were all broken on Docker for Windows pre-WSL2. Seems to be exactly the issue you are hitting. So if you want to stick to Windows, your best bet is to adopt WSL2 as quickly as possible. Note, that most people are migrating to it from Hyper-V - so this may not get fixed for Hyper-V at all.

Comment: @taleodor I investigated a litte further and I guess you are right. Even if there is a hack for Hyper-V it is not worthwhile to push in that direction. Thank you.